# Class gets added too early causing the sidebar to 'jump'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried reproducing this problem in jsFiddle but unfortunately I couldn't. Basically, I'm using the JavaScript below to add a `fixed` class to the sidebar once it passes the threshold. When the bottom of the sidebar reaches the bottom of its parent container (`#content`), the `bottom` class is supposed to be added.

Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

You can see a live version of this at http://vice.com. Try scrolling down and you will see what I mean.

Currently, my test site is at http://keebs.com/sandbox. On the home page, you can see that the `fixed` class gets added but the `bottom` class gets added way too early causing the sidebar to jump to the bottom before it hits the bottom.

JavaScript

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var threshold = 654;

    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold)
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    var position = jQuery("#content").position();
    var content_top =  position.top;
    var check = (jQuery('#content').height() + content_top) - jQuery('#sidebar').height();
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= check)
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('bottom');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('bottom');
});
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 220px;
}
#sidebar.fixed {
  margin-left: 720px;
  position: fixed;
  right: auto;
  top: 173px;
}
#sidebar.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I'm sorry that I don't have a jsFiddle but would anyone be willing to take a look at the site to see what may be causing this issue? I am also open to paying someone to help me out with this.

Comment: you might have already tried this but can you `console.log` your vars and scroll to see why the calculation triggers early?

Comment: @greener Thank you. I just tried `console.log` on `position`, `content_top`, and `check` and this was the output: `Object {top: 194, left: 0} custom-js.js?ver=1.0.0:108 194 custom-js.js?ver=1.0.0:109 1471`. However, I am not exactly sure how this can help me understand why the calculation triggers early.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like this: http://codepen.io/kyleatfine/pen/Dyiba

You actually need more arguments in your if statement, and require and else if as well.

In my pen, I've made it so that it detects the height of the header, detects how far you would scroll to reach the footer and then adds and removes classes accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
  var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight() - 20; // Change happens 20px sooner now
  var heightToFooter = $('.wrap').outerHeight() + headerHeight - $('.sidebar').outerHeight() - 20;
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();


  $(window).scroll(function() {
     scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

     if (scrollTop >= headerHeight && scrollTop < heightToFooter) {
       $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
     } else if (scrollTop > headerHeight && scrollTop >= heightToFooter) {
       $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
       $sidebar.addClass('bottom');
     } else {
       $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
       $sidebar.removeClass('bottom');
     }
  });
});
```

As you can see, it auto detects the heights for you and then checks that it's gone far enough to be fixed, but not far enough to be bottom. Should do the trick for you.

**Update**

In response to your comment, that addition is simple and requires two steps.

1) Your fixed class requires `top: 20px; bottom: auto` and your bottom class requires `top: auto; bottom: 20px;` I have always found this solution, to reset position values with auto, to be helpful when placing a div with a different position attribute.

2) Simply subtract the number 20 from the headerHeight and heightToFooter variables. The outerHeight() function gives us a number without 'px' attached, so we don't need to subtract 20px from it. Doing this adds the classes 20px sooner than before.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I know you made it just like the gif in the original post but would it be possible to have this replicate more of my setup on my test site? For example, my header is fixed on top and the sidebar becomes fixed 20px below the header and is supposed to stop being fixed 20px from the top of the footer. Maybe then I can try to apply this to my setup, hopefully.

Comment: I updated my answer and my CodePen to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem and I have created something similar to this a little while ago.

http://www.darrencousins.com/lab/sticky-menu/

Hope it helps

**HTML**

```
        <div id="contentContainer">

        <div id="headerContent">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio oculos ut sua in fuerat eum in modo invenit! Civitate virginitatis tibi alloquitur hanc enim materiam. Tyrio alius ut casus adprehendens lugubri vestigia o inter. Filia navem auditum rationem superius dixisti 'membris data profectus ait in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit erat. Hellenico clamabat vidit loco dedit erat votum faciente humana gaudet uxoris tibi cum obiectum dixit hoc ait Cumque autem nobiscum. Ex hic nisi ductus vehor matrimonio accipiam. Facere potest ei primum subsannio oculos ne velocitate mare convivio.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="bodyContent">
            <h1>Left menu sticks when scrolled to page top</h1>
            <p>01. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio.</p>
            <p>02. Peracta licet tali hac insultare mortuorum meus. Allocutus ait est Apollonius ut libertatem non dum, videns sed esse ait Cumque hoc. Sic genero coruscus eum ego quod non solutionem invenisti naufragus habuisti sit Mariae maximas hanc legibus Antiochiam innocentem si. A his singulare tertio eam est cum autem illud cenam ita cum unde. Hanc si mihi quidditas iter patri. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier autem illud meae ad quia ei. Boreas quam cara die ad nomine sed eu fugiens laudo in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non ait. Indulgentia pedes rex Dionysiadi suo aperuit. Antiochus sed dominum vidit D</p>
            <p>03. Mauricii materialia sola ait Cumque ego quod una, ex quae ait in fuerat construeret cena. Coram posset Denique laetare in lucem concitaverunt in fuerat. Notus ingreditur ipse dignitatem in lucem in lucem exempli paupers coniunx minus. Iuravi potest meum festinus pervenissem. Eiusdem ordo quos annorum nostros versi tuam, neptuno ait Cumque materia puella est cum! Accedens est amet consensit cellula filia in modo ad te, singulas cotidie hoc ambulare est cum unde non solutionem innocentem tantusque </p>
            <p>04. Sic ut a his domino Lycoridem in deinde vero non potentiae quem es illum decidat quam crucis in. Communicatio mihi cum suam ut casus tui convenientibus ne videret quaeritur vero diam ille advenit ego Pentapolim Cyrenaeorum tertia! X domum Taliarchus disponis a a civitas Conservus mihi, abstulit meis caligine tempestas sabano praeclusoque sponte profundo. Christe in rei sensibilium iussit hoc, coniunx caritate completae ad nomine Hesterna. Domini includeret Tharsiam Hellenicus sui coniungens in modo. Itaque completum ad quia illum decidat quam dolore cruciatus in modo invenit ubi ait. Neptune reddens pater in modo cavendum es ego quod ait regem consolatus dum est amet Cur meae. Aliquid se ad suis ut sua confusus eos. Cyrenaeam plus quem es ego esse ait! Cives ego Pentapolim Cyrenaeorum tertia veni illis atque ut a a. Domus filia omnes deo adiuves finem volo, fit proponebat vidit Dionysiadi suo celaturos Tantus puella. Neptunalia festinare decenter ortam pectore villicus. Toro frumento manu certas parturiens a, christe in lucem in lucem.</p>
            <p>05. Iacentem in lucem in modo invenit ubi diu desideriis meo, nisi se vero diam ' Apollonium sit aliquip ipsa mihi. Palpat venas tanquam vero quo sanctis venias in lucem exitum vivit. Palpat venas tanquam vero rex ut a, animae ait est se ad per te. Horreo Athenagora secundum ei primum gaudet uxoris tibi alloquitur vidit ad per. Pertulit sed dominum sit in lucem exempli paupers. Disce Apollonius non ait Cumque ego esse deprecor, sic genero nomine Maria cum magna amici rex. Inter tua vero quo sanctis venias in. Pater ostendit Apollonius in lucem genero nomine Stranguillio in fuerat construeret cena reges. Quod non coepit cenam veniebant est in modo invenit nutricis suo. Theophilo ex civibus corporis particularis mortem sunt amore excitat si mihi Tyrum in fuerat. Eam ad suis Tyrium coniugem in modo cavendum es sed haec.</p>
            <p>06. Scelus euismod tollam impedit mecum loci haec, re est in modo cavendum es. Aderit omnia claustrum Bone de tuae infami cum. Quidditas tuo lugenti permittis enim ad nomine Hesterna studiis ascende ad te finis puellam materia ad per. Suam ad quia iuvenis naves. Nulla enim ad te in rei exultant deo adiuves finem, abiecto hac auxilium super audire servi Dianae non solutionem invenerunt. Amen ad suis Tyrium coniugem Chaldaeorum in modo genito in. Curro vicina haec sed quod tamen cursu agis cives perfusa commendavit patris Tyrius tu illum vero diam ille eum. Ascendi in modo invenit iuvenem discessum adulta quid ait in rei completo litus sua coniuge sancta justo forma in. Video qui enim materiam individuis qui dicens hoc Apollonius. Gaudeo in modo compungi mulierem volutpat. Autem est cum autem nobiscum laetitia haec sed eu fides se ad per animum est Apollonius mihi. Scola veniamus est in deinde plectrum anni ipsa Invitamus me. Toto determinata diebus paululum seclusit in rei civibus nescis haec.</p>

            <p><a class="showContent" href="#">Expand / Contract Content</a></p>
            <div class="collapsable">
                <p>06a. Introivit dic gubernius eum est cum magna. Alia qui auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis ut sua. In fuerat est amet Cur meae in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non potentiae. Navis fortiter quam cara in rei civibus in deinde duas recitare. Horreo Athenagora mihi cum suam ut a. Dionysiadis eum filiam sum ad nomine sed dominum vidit pater. Volentes mihi cum suam vidit Dionysiadi. Mea vero quo accumsan in deinde duas particularis dedit beneficio, communicatio mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum civibus unde tu.</p>
                <p>06b. Dicentem Austri ventriculum defunctae cubiculo forma anima te princeps audito claudi in rei sensibilium iussit in rei finibus veteres hoc. Potentiam suos exteriores non ait in fuerat accidens quam dicentes multa dolores in fuerat se vero non ait. Num praebeo deum roseo commendavit fideliter harena in lucem. Spero mihi cum suam non dum veniens indica enim formam cum obiectum est cum magna. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier quae vero non solutionem inveni. Laetare in fuerat accidens inquit merui litore, tharsos princeps age cum obiectum est in. Celebrantur nuptias iam est amet Cur meae in deinde cepit roseo commendavit fideliter harena in. Veniente mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum cui Tharsia Theophilo ex hic ait est se in.</p>
            </div>

            <p>07. Introivit dic gubernius eum est cum magna. Alia qui auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis ut sua. In fuerat est amet Cur meae in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non potentiae. Navis fortiter quam cara in rei civibus in deinde duas recitare. Horreo Athenagora mihi cum suam ut a. Dionysiadis eum filiam sum ad nomine sed dominum vidit pater. Volentes mihi cum suam vidit Dionysiadi. Mea vero quo accumsan in deinde duas particularis dedit beneficio, communicatio mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum civibus unde tu.</p>
            <p>08. Dicentem Austri ventriculum defunctae cubiculo forma anima te princeps audito claudi in rei sensibilium iussit in rei finibus veteres hoc. Potentiam suos exteriores non ait in fuerat accidens quam dicentes multa dolores in fuerat se vero non ait. Num praebeo deum roseo commendavit fideliter harena in lucem. Spero mihi cum suam non dum veniens indica enim formam cum obiectum est cum magna. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier quae vero non solutionem inveni. Laetare in fuerat accidens inquit merui litore, tharsos princeps age cum obiectum est in. Celebrantur nuptias iam est amet Cur meae in deinde cepit roseo commendavit fideliter harena in. Veniente mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum cui Tharsia Theophilo ex hic ait est se in.</p>

            <p>09. Labore in lucem exempli paupers coniunx caritate completae ad suis est se est cum unde. Antiochi suae adulescentis Stranguillio eam in modo, ac esse haec sed esse haec sed. Atqui plurium venenosamque serpentium ne civitatis civium eum. Auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis alteri ad quia quod eam ad te. X domum Taliarchus eius ad per dicis eo cardine populis ut casus. Africus hortamento laetus moritur ad te sed eu. Proiciens te in lucem concitaverunt in lucem. Male habitu rubor virginitatem sunt antecedente tuus factum ei sed esse deprecor! Tharsia adulescens longum terrae denegavit suis ut libertatem adhuc quid populi. Zurziaca in fuerat construeret in fuerat est in, accedens est se in lucem exempli paupers coniunx. Horreo Athenagora mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum condono.</p>
            <p>10. Male habitu introisti sit dolor Jesus Circumdat flante vestibus indulgentia perrexit est amet coram regis in. At at at ipsum ait regem Boreas quam cara in. Supponite facultatibus actum se in lucem genero quod non coepit. Agere videre Proicite a a patriam sum concumbens vero non potentiae amore nec 'pectore zaetam at eius. Sed esse ait regem adventu nihil impetrat est cum obiectum ait est se in. Bene ventis non solutionem ascendens sed. Meam ad per accipere sibi adsedit. Coniugem in lucem genero coruscus eum. Eam eos est Apollonius mihi quidditas patria navem aspectum cui, concursus male nuptiarum solum puella mihi esse deprecor Athenagora ut diem finito convocatis ad quia. Consuetudo aut ante leni in fuerat se ad te, rhenum ibat est amet amet coram regis iam. Bene nostrae iam insulam quod ait est se ad nomine, filiam vel ita in rei sensibilium iussit est amet Cur meae. Actum se ad nomine Stranguillio in lucem exitum vivit in rei exultant deo adoptavit cum.</p>
            <p>11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio oculos ut sua in fuerat eum in modo invenit! Civitate virginitatis tibi alloquitur hanc enim materiam. Tyrio alius ut casus adprehendens lugubri vestigia o inter. Filia navem auditum rationem superius dixisti 'membris data profectus ait in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit erat. Hellenico clamabat vidit loco dedit erat votum faciente humana gaudet uxoris tibi cum obiectum dixit hoc ait Cumque autem nobiscum. Ex hic nisi ductus vehor matrimonio accipiam. Facere potest ei primum subsannio oculos ne velocitate mare convivio.</p>
            <p>12. Peracta licet tali hac insultare mortuorum meus. Allocutus ait est Apollonius ut libertatem non dum, videns sed esse ait Cumque hoc. Sic genero coruscus eum ego quod non solutionem invenisti naufragus habuisti sit Mariae maximas hanc legibus Antiochiam innocentem si. A his singulare tertio eam est cum autem illud cenam ita cum unde. Hanc si mihi quidditas iter patri. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier autem illud meae ad quia ei. Boreas quam cara die ad nomine sed eu fugiens laudo in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non ait. Indulgentia pedes rex Dionysiadi suo aperuit. Antiochus sed dominum vidit Dionysiadi rex in fuerat construeret cena reges undis Tharsiam. X domum aversae regi accidens quam dicentes parem, navibus mensam ne velocitate renovasti dominus deprecatur videns mihi. Dabit es audito sed esse ait regem Boreas ingreditur ad per, tace mordeo tertia navigavit volente in fuerat eum in. Iterum naufragum manus in fuerat eum istam vero quo est se est cum. Possit scitis quas praesenti X domum aversae regi alius coagulato scelesta.</p>
            <p>13. Mauricii materialia sola ait Cumque ego quod una, ex quae ait in fuerat construeret cena. Coram posset Denique laetare in lucem concitaverunt in fuerat. Notus ingreditur ipse dignitatem in lucem in lucem exempli paupers coniunx minus. Iuravi potest meum festinus pervenissem. Eiusdem ordo quos annorum nostros versi tuam, neptuno ait Cumque materia puella est cum! Accedens est amet consensit cellula filia in modo ad te, singulas cotidie hoc ambulare est cum unde non solutionem innocentem tantusque amorem civium takimata. Volentes mihi cum unde tu mihi quidditas tuo dolor ad per. Tyrio alius certe est se vero cum unde tu mihi Tyrum in lucem exitum atque album Apolloni codicellos iam. Probo artium liberalium perfectionis virgo permitte a civitas iter indica enim ad quia illum. Contremuit in deinde cepit roseo commendavit patris super. Venis potest contremiscunt pater ostendit Apollonius eius sed dominum in. Austri ventriculum defunctae cubiculo forma in deinde duas recitare. Scimus fundamentum in rei finibus veteres hoc ambulare dolor invenerit adduci aut ante Retrorsum redire ad per sanctus singulos domum.</p>
            <p>14. Sic ut a his domino Lycoridem in deinde vero non potentiae quem es illum decidat quam crucis in. Communicatio mihi cum suam ut casus tui convenientibus ne videret quaeritur vero diam ille advenit ego Pentapolim Cyrenaeorum tertia! X domum Taliarchus disponis a a civitas Conservus mihi, abstulit meis caligine tempestas sabano praeclusoque sponte profundo. Christe in rei sensibilium iussit hoc, coniunx caritate completae ad nomine Hesterna. Domini includeret Tharsiam Hellenicus sui coniungens in modo. Itaque completum ad quia illum decidat quam dolore cruciatus in modo invenit ubi ait. Neptune reddens pater in modo cavendum es ego quod ait regem consolatus dum est amet Cur meae. Aliquid se ad suis ut sua confusus eos. Cyrenaeam plus quem es ego esse ait! Cives ego Pentapolim Cyrenaeorum tertia veni illis atque ut a a. Domus filia omnes deo adiuves finem volo, fit proponebat vidit Dionysiadi suo celaturos Tantus puella. Neptunalia festinare decenter ortam pectore villicus. Toro frumento manu certas parturiens a, christe in lucem in lucem.</p>
            <p>15. Iacentem in lucem in modo invenit ubi diu desideriis meo, nisi se vero diam ' Apollonium sit aliquip ipsa mihi. Palpat venas tanquam vero quo sanctis venias in lucem exitum vivit. Palpat venas tanquam vero rex ut a, animae ait est se ad per te. Horreo Athenagora secundum ei primum gaudet uxoris tibi alloquitur vidit ad per. Pertulit sed dominum sit in lucem exempli paupers. Disce Apollonius non ait Cumque ego esse deprecor, sic genero nomine Maria cum magna amici rex. Inter tua vero quo sanctis venias in. Pater ostendit Apollonius in lucem genero nomine Stranguillio in fuerat construeret cena reges. Quod non coepit cenam veniebant est in modo invenit nutricis suo. Theophilo ex civibus corporis particularis mortem sunt amore excitat si mihi Tyrum in fuerat. Eam ad suis Tyrium coniugem in modo cavendum es sed haec.</p>
            <p>16. Scelus euismod tollam impedit mecum loci haec, re est in modo cavendum es. Aderit omnia claustrum Bone de tuae infami cum. Quidditas tuo lugenti permittis enim ad nomine Hesterna studiis ascende ad te finis puellam materia ad per. Suam ad quia iuvenis naves. Nulla enim ad te in rei exultant deo adiuves finem, abiecto hac auxilium super audire servi Dianae non solutionem invenerunt. Amen ad suis Tyrium coniugem Chaldaeorum in modo genito in. Curro vicina haec sed quod tamen cursu agis cives perfusa commendavit patris Tyrius tu illum vero diam ille eum. Ascendi in modo invenit iuvenem discessum adulta quid ait in rei completo litus sua coniuge sancta justo forma in. Video qui enim materiam individuis qui dicens hoc Apollonius. Gaudeo in modo compungi mulierem volutpat. Autem est cum autem nobiscum laetitia haec sed eu fides se ad per animum est Apollonius mihi. Scola veniamus est in deinde plectrum anni ipsa Invitamus me. Toto determinata diebus paululum seclusit in rei civibus nescis haec.</p>
            <p>17. Introivit dic gubernius eum est cum magna. Alia qui auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis ut sua. In fuerat est amet Cur meae in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non potentiae. Navis fortiter quam cara in rei civibus in deinde duas recitare. Horreo Athenagora mihi cum suam ut a. Dionysiadis eum filiam sum ad nomine sed dominum vidit pater. Volentes mihi cum suam vidit Dionysiadi. Mea vero quo accumsan in deinde duas particularis dedit beneficio, communicatio mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum civibus unde tu.</p>
            <p>18. Dicentem Austri ventriculum defunctae cubiculo forma anima te princeps audito claudi in rei sensibilium iussit in rei finibus veteres hoc. Potentiam suos exteriores non ait in fuerat accidens quam dicentes multa dolores in fuerat se vero non ait. Num praebeo deum roseo commendavit fideliter harena in lucem. Spero mihi cum suam non dum veniens indica enim formam cum obiectum est cum magna. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier quae vero non solutionem inveni. Laetare in fuerat accidens inquit merui litore, tharsos princeps age cum obiectum est in. Celebrantur nuptias iam est amet Cur meae in deinde cepit roseo commendavit fideliter harena in. Veniente mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum cui Tharsia Theophilo ex hic ait est se in.</p>
            <p>19. Labore in lucem exempli paupers coniunx caritate completae ad suis est se est cum unde. Antiochi suae adulescentis Stranguillio eam in modo, ac esse haec sed esse haec sed. Atqui plurium venenosamque serpentium ne civitatis civium eum. Auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis alteri ad quia quod eam ad te. X domum Taliarchus eius ad per dicis eo cardine populis ut casus. Africus hortamento laetus moritur ad te sed eu. Proiciens te in lucem concitaverunt in lucem. Male habitu rubor virginitatem sunt antecedente tuus factum ei sed esse deprecor! Tharsia adulescens longum terrae denegavit suis ut libertatem adhuc quid populi. Zurziaca in fuerat construeret in fuerat est in, accedens est se in lucem exempli paupers coniunx. Horreo Athenagora mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum condono.</p>

            <p><a class="showContent" href="#">Expand / Contract Content</a></p>
            <div class="collapsable">
                <p>19a. Introivit dic gubernius eum est cum magna. Alia qui auri Neptunus spatia tribulatione ad suis ut sua. In fuerat est amet Cur meae in deinde plectrum anni ipsa quod non potentiae. Navis fortiter quam cara in rei civibus in deinde duas recitare. Horreo Athenagora mihi cum suam ut a. Dionysiadis eum filiam sum ad nomine sed dominum vidit pater. Volentes mihi cum suam vidit Dionysiadi. Mea vero quo accumsan in deinde duas particularis dedit beneficio, communicatio mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum civibus unde tu.</p>
                <p>19b. Dicentem Austri ventriculum defunctae cubiculo forma anima te princeps audito claudi in rei sensibilium iussit in rei finibus veteres hoc. Potentiam suos exteriores non ait in fuerat accidens quam dicentes multa dolores in fuerat se vero non ait. Num praebeo deum roseo commendavit fideliter harena in lucem. Spero mihi cum suam non dum veniens indica enim formam cum obiectum est cum magna. Nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier quae vero non solutionem inveni. Laetare in fuerat accidens inquit merui litore, tharsos princeps age cum obiectum est in. Celebrantur nuptias iam est amet Cur meae in deinde cepit roseo commendavit fideliter harena in. Veniente mihi servitute coniunx efficerer nuptiarum cui Tharsia Theophilo ex hic ait est se in.</p>
            </div>

            <p>20. Male habitu introisti sit dolor Jesus Circumdat flante vestibus indulgentia perrexit est amet coram regis in. At at at ipsum ait regem Boreas quam cara in. Supponite facultatibus actum se in lucem genero quod non coepit. Agere videre Proicite a a patriam sum concumbens vero non potentiae amore nec 'pectore zaetam at eius. Sed esse ait regem adventu nihil impetrat est cum obiectum ait est se in. Bene ventis non solutionem ascendens sed. Meam ad per accipere sibi adsedit. Coniugem in lucem genero coruscus eum. Eam eos est Apollonius mihi quidditas patria navem aspectum cui, concursus male nuptiarum solum puella mihi esse deprecor Athenagora ut diem finito convocatis ad quia. Consuetudo aut ante leni in fuerat se ad te, rhenum ibat est amet amet coram regis iam. Bene nostrae iam insulam quod ait est se ad nomine, filiam vel ita in rei sensibilium iussit est amet Cur meae. Actum se ad nomine Stranguillio in lucem exitum vivit in rei exultant deo adoptavit cum.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>

                <li>01</li>
                <li>02</li>
                <li>03</li>
                <li>04</li>
                <li>05</li>
                <li>06</li>
                <li>07</li>
                <li>08</li>
                <li>09</li>
                <li>10</li>

                <li>11</li>
                <li>12</li>
                <li>13</li>
                <li>14</li>
                <li>15</li>
                <li>16</li>
                <li>17</li>
                <li>18</li>
                <li>19</li>
                <li>20</li>

                <li>21</li>
                <li>22</li>
                <li>23</li>
                <li>24</li>
                <li>25</li>
                <li>26</li>
                <li>27</li>
                <li>28</li>
                <li>29</li>
                <li>30</li>

                <li>31</li>
                <li>32</li>
                <li>33</li>
                <li>34</li>
                <li>35</li>
                <li>36</li>
                <li>37</li>
                <li>38</li>
                <li>39</li>
                <li>40</li>

                <li>41</li>
                <li>42</li>
                <li>43</li>
                <li>44</li>
                <li>45</li>
                <li>46</li>
                <li>47</li>
                <li>48</li>
                <li>49</li>
                <li>50</li>


            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="footerContent">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio oculos ut sua in fuerat eum in modo invenit! Civitate virginitatis tibi alloquitur hanc enim materiam. Tyrio alius ut casus adprehendens lugubri vestigia o inter. Filia navem auditum rationem superius dixisti 'membris data profectus ait in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit erat. Hellenico clamabat vidit loco dedit erat votum faciente humana gaudet uxoris tibi cum obiectum dixit hoc ait Cumque autem nobiscum. Ex hic nisi ductus vehor matrimonio accipiam. Facere potest ei primum subsannio oculos ne velocitate mare convivio.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio oculos ut sua in fuerat eum in modo invenit! Civitate virginitatis tibi alloquitur hanc enim materiam. Tyrio alius ut casus adprehendens lugubri vestigia o inter. Filia navem auditum rationem superius dixisti 'membris data profectus ait in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit erat. Hellenico clamabat vidit loco dedit erat votum faciente humana gaudet uxoris tibi cum obiectum dixit hoc ait Cumque autem nobiscum. Ex hic nisi ductus vehor matrimonio accipiam. Facere potest ei primum subsannio oculos ne velocitate mare convivio.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, materia amicis in. Nescimus de memor nostris qui dicens hoc, sui Care genitorem ipsam mecum est Apollonius. Apollonii corporis optime re est cum unde meae ceroma fronte comico hac navi quia. Filiae multi capillos quam crucis coniunx minus, 'Ipsius dum autem nobiscum paulo aureos fecit. Cupis ei primum subsannio oculos ut sua in fuerat eum in modo invenit! Civitate virginitatis tibi alloquitur hanc enim materiam. Tyrio alius ut casus adprehendens lugubri vestigia o inter. Filia navem auditum rationem superius dixisti 'membris data profectus ait in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit erat. Hellenico clamabat vidit loco dedit erat votum faciente humana gaudet uxoris tibi cum obiectum dixit hoc ait Cumque autem nobiscum. Ex hic nisi ductus vehor matrimonio accipiam. Facere potest ei primum subsannio oculos ne velocitate mare convivio.</p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    html, body              {font:0.9em/1.1em "Arial", sans-serif;}

h1                      {line-height:1.2em}

p#scrollValue           {position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}
p#docHeight             {position:fixed; top:20px; left:0;}


#contentContainer       {margin:30px auto 0; width:600px; overflow:hidden; border:3px solid lime;}

    #headerContent      {margin:0 0 30px; border:3px solid cyan;}

    #bodyContent        {float:left; margin:0 0 30px; width:400px; border:3px solid blue}

    .collapsable        {display:none}

    #menu               {float:right; width:100px; border:3px solid red; background:white;}

    #footerContent      {clear:both; border:3px solid cyan;}

    .fixToTop           {position:fixed; top:0px; right:50%; margin-right:-300px}
    .fixToSide          {position:fixed; right:0; margin-right:0;}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    //Initialisation

        var scrollPosition = 0;

    //DOM ELEMENTS
        var parentContainer = $("#contentContainer")  //parent container of content & menu or sidebar
        var nonFixedObject = $("#bodyContent");  //scrollable content
        var fixedObject = $('#menu');  //fixed menu or sidebar

        var contentOffsetTop = $(nonFixedObject).offset().top;  // get content offset from top
        var menuOffsetTop = $(fixedObject).offset().top;  //get fixed content offset from top

        var contentHeight = getContentHeight();
        var menuHeight = getMenuHeight();
        var offsetBottom = calculateOffSetBottom();

        var containerWidth = $(parentContainer).width();  //get the width of the main container

        var screenResizerTimer;  //global timer for resizing event  



        $(window).scroll(function ()
        {
                scrollPosition = getScrollPosition();

                if(scrollPosition > contentOffsetTop)
                {
                    $(fixedObject).attr('style','');

                    $(fixedObject).addClass('fixToTop');

                    if(scrollPosition > offsetBottom)
                    {
                        $(fixedObject).css({'position':'absolute', 'top':offsetBottom});
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( $(fixedObject).hasClass('fixToSide') )
                    {
                        $(fixedObject).css({'top':menuOffsetTop - scrollPosition});
                    }

                    if ( $(fixedObject).hasClass('fixToTop') )
                    {
                        $(fixedObject).removeClass('fixToTop');
                    }
                }           
        });





    //When we resize the window smaller than the container, attach the class to stick the menu to the browser window
    //instead of the parent container
        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            clearTimeout(screenResizerTimer);

            screenResizerTimer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                var bodyWidth = $('body').width();  //get the body width

                if (bodyWidth <= containerWidth) //if browser window is smaller than content width
                {
                    $(fixedObject).addClass('fixToSide')  //then add the class
                }
                else
                {
                    $(fixedObject).removeClass('fixToSide')  //then remove the class
                }

            },10);
        });



    $('.showContent').toggle(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().next().slideDown(
            function()
            {
                getContentHeight();
                calculateOffSetBottom()
            });

    }, function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().next().slideUp(
            function()
            {
                getContentHeight();
                calculateOffSetBottom()
            });
    })




    //-----------------------------------
    //          FUNCTIONS
    //-----------------------------------
        function getContentHeight()
        {
            contentHeight = $(nonFixedObject).height();  //get content height
            return contentHeight;
        }


        function getMenuHeight()
        {
            menuHeight = $(fixedObject).height();  //get fixed content height
            return menuHeight;
        }


        function calculateOffSetBottom()
        {
            offsetBottom = contentHeight - (menuHeight - menuOffsetTop); //bottom point at which fixed content moves again
            return offsetBottom;
        }

        function getScrollPosition()
        {
            scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop()
            return scrollPosition
        }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. However, since I have auto-load masonry on the home page, I'm having a bit of a hard time getting the code to work on my test site.